# rerender view when model property change in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, highcharts

I'm trying to develop a small app using EmberJS and HighchartJS, and I have some problem to re-render the the HighChartJS after the Model property has changed. This is http://www.loancomparison.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

```
App.Loan = DS.Model.extend({
    name : DS.attr('string'),
    principal : DS.attr('number'),
    interest_rate : DS.attr('number'),
    months_to_pay : DS.attr('number')
});

App.LoansView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: "loans",

    loansChanged: function() {
        //this.rerender();
        Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, 'propertyChanged');
    }.observes('controller.@each.principal', 'controller.@each.name', 'controller.@each.interest_rate', 'controller.@each.months_to_pay'),

    propertyChanged : function() {
       console.log("property changed");
       this.loadHighChart(); // This will load the highchart function.
    },
});
```

What I want is to notify the view whenever the model property **finishes** their change. However, when using observes, it notify the view when the model starts to change. This causes the scheduleOnce to run at the initial state of model property change only.

**Edit: Resolved**
The solution for this turned out to be very simple that I just need to create a "modified" property under the model loan. Then whenever the edit is made, I update this model. Now the view just need to observe the change of this "modified" property.

Comment: when is the model property change "finished"?

Comment: I want to have the notification send to the view after user has done editing. This also mean the model property finished its changing.

Comment: Why don't you just run the changed functions when the user clicks the 'Save' button?

Comment: +1 Remove the loansChanged method, and add `this.loadHighChart()` to the `save` action https://github.com/pmkhoa/loan-comparison/blob/master/source/assets/js/app/controllers/loanController.js#L7

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to hook into the save `action` within your `LoanController`: https://github.com/pmkhoa/loan-comparison/blob/master/source/assets/js/app/controllers/loanController.js#L7

You can communicate really easily between views and controllers by using `Ember.Evented`:

```
App.LoanController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(Ember.Evented, { <--PASS IN EMBER.EVENTED     
  //...
    save: function () {
      this.set('isEditing', false);
      this.get('model').save().then(function () {
        this.trigger('highChartReload'); 
      }.bind(this));
    },
  //...
});
```

Notice that I've passed `Ember.Evented` into the controller (just like you would with any mixin...) and I've added a `trigger` to the save `action`.

Now, we'll want to listen for that event within the view: https://github.com/pmkhoa/loan-comparison/blob/master/source/assets/js/app/views/loansView.js#L3

```
App.LoansView = Ember.View.extend({
  //...
  didInsertElement: function () {
    this.get('controller.controllers.loan').on('highChartReload', $.proxy(this.loadHighChart, this));
  },
  //...
});
```

Now the view will listen to `LoanController` for the event to trigger, then fire off the `loadHighChart` method.

The last thing to do will be to tell the `LoansController` to `need` 'loan':

```
App.LoansController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({ 
  needs: ['loan'],
  //...
});
```

That should do it. Hope that helps!

Comment: I implemented this to my app, however the view didn't listen to the LoanController to trigger the highChartReload event. https://github.com/pmkhoa/loan-comparison/blob/master/source/assets/js/app/views/loansView.js#L5

Comment: Hmm... try adding a breakpoint or a console.log to the `didInsertElement` hook to check both `this.get('controller.needs')` and `this.get('controller').toString()` Also, any errors in the console?

Comment: Also, are you seeing output for this console log: https://github.com/pmkhoa/loan-comparison/blob/master/source/assets/js/app/controllers/loanController.js#L12

Comment: I can see the "reload" log after the save button clicked. And the console log of this.get('controller.needs') & this.get('controller').toString() are: 
- ["loan", nextObject: function ...]
- <App.LoansController:ember356>
Not sure why the view didn't listen to the event.

Comment: Hmm... I suppose that it could be that the trigger is taking place within an action. See my updated edit.

Comment: Hi Matthew, I have spent several hours debugging this; however, I couldn't find the solution yet. I also implemented your edit version above, unfortunately the view didn't listen to that trigger event yet. My question now is how can we debug/know that we know the `highChartReload` will fire off, and how can we tell if the Loan controller in the `loansView` is listening to that event. Thankks !

Comment: @KhoaPham Any chance you could throw the app up onto a jsbin or something? It looks like it should work to me, but I may have overlooked something.

Comment: It turns out there's a very simple solution for this. I just need to create another "modified" property for the loan model. Whenever someone makes the edit, I update this property and make this view observes this changes. Voila! Thanks for your help Matthew!

Comment: Awesome! You should post your answer as an alternative approach.